# Interaction tracking on a container embeded movie

Tags: flash

Assuming there is an SWF built by a 3d party that is deployed on my website (most typical example, a flash ad), is it technically possible to create another SWF (container) that embeds the original SWF and is capable of counting clicks and capturing hover events on it? Are there any examples of such implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sample:

```
var external:DisplayObject;

var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
loaderContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

var loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
loader.load(new URLRequest(SWF_PATH), loaderContext);

private function onLoadComplete(event:Event):void {
    this.external = this.loader.content;
    this.external.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);
    this.addChild(this.external);
}

private function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void {

}

private function onMouseClick(event:MouseEvent): void {

}
```